# Validation error: PayPal IPN response from a different email address

Tags: validation, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've used plugins to set up my ticket sales. I'm testing my site in Sandbox mode and I'm receiving this error after going through the Paypal process (which is showing in sandbox mode):

Validation error: PayPal IPN response from a different email address (sarah-facilitator@XXXXX). Order status changed from processing to on-hold.

Paypal created the facilitator email for me and I'm using those details as well as the supplied sandbox API user/password/sig on my website

As I'm in Australia, I've also set up my site to accept USD.

I'm not sure what's happening that I'd get this error.

Answer (score 2):

the PayPal IPN response usually contains a "receiver=" as well as a "business=" paramter.

Depending on the script you're using, there will be a validation of the receiving e-mail address. If it does not match the one configured in your shopping cart / site, some shopping carts will throw this error message.

You can verify the IPN message text through https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history (first login to the sandbox account under www.sandbox.paypal.com)and see if the receiving / business e-mail address matches the one configured on your site.

Of course, it'd help to extend the logging of your IPN script to contain some meaningful information (e.g. "Receiver e-mail xxxx does not match configured e-mail xxxxx").

Cheers,
Martin